# Can't shutdown eth0 interface

Tags: raspbian, networking

I'm running a standard Raspbian installation (2014-01-07 image version, no extra software installed). All I want to do is to shut down the `eth0` interface. The problem is that this works for a few seconds only, and then the interface all of a sudden is automatically up again.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

I've tried shutting the interface down with both `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` and `sudo ifdown eth0` to no avail. I suspect this problem is somehow related to DHCP or the `dhclient` program itself, since the interface releases its DHCP-assigned IP address for a short time, but apparently re-installs that same IP address just a few seconds later again.

Can anybody help me here? I'm stuck with this. Thank you very much!

Comment: take a look at this http://superuser.com/questions/695297/disable-network-adaptor-eth0-on-debian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what caused this problem, but upgrading to the latest Raspbian image (version  2014-09-09) solved the problem for me.

Comment: Have you tried the solution suggested by @MarkKomarinski before upgrading your system?

Comment: Yes, I did try `sudo ifdown eth0` (as already posted within the question itself). Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. The interface always was automatically back up just a few seconds after that. No idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sudo ifdown eth0`.  You're correct that if dhclient is still running it'll probably bring the interface back up.  If you use `ifconfig` that won't stop dhclient.  Using `ifdown` should do that.

Answer (score -1):

There's an answer to this specific problem on the raspbian page at https://www.raspbian.org/PiscesImages - at the bottom a note attached to description of version 1 of the pisces system release.

Comment: Welcome to raspberrypi@se. Please do include the relevant part of the solution into the post itself, to prevent link-rot. I'll set -1 just until the post is edited.

Answer (score -3):

Try these commands:

`ip link set eth0 down`

`ip link set eth0 up`

Comment: This  is a very low quality answer. It provides nothing but a couple of commands. How does this work? why does it work when other similar things do not (sudo ifdown eth0 etc.)?